# dlang compare types: cannot use '==' with types

Tags: d, static-analysis

I have the following line in my code:

```d
static if (typeof(val) == string) {
```

It is not compiling and returning the error `Error: incompatible types for ((string) == (string)): cannot use '==' with types`.  What is the correct way to check the type of a variable?

Comment: I believe this may help: http://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#IsExpression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to use an [`is` expression](http://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#IsExpression) around it: `is(A == b)` like this:

```d
static if (is(typeof(val) == string)) {
```

Comment: So is the behaviour of `==` context-sensitive, so inside an `is()` the `==` can take a pair of types as arguments, but not outside? Weird stuff, but well done.

Comment: The `is()` expression is magic syntax that isn't really related to the others. It does type comparison and is also used in some of the reflection low level parts (like there's `is(Params func == __parameters)` which extracts a parameter list and declares a new symbol to hold them rather than being a traditional comparison at all). So you should think of it as being a wholly separate thing, despite sharing a keyword with the `is` operator (`a is b`) and symbols with equality and inheritance `is(A : some_interface)` returns true if A is implicitly convertible to it, but works on more than class!